# having trouble getting my code to run at all

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addeventlistener

the button wont submit the code and return the if statement

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Body Mass Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Body Mass Calculator</h1>
    <br>
    <h3>Today, we're going to calculate your body's BMI.</h3>
    <br>
    <form>
        <label for="height">Height</label>: 
        <input type="number" id="feet" min="1" max="9" step="1" required><label for="feet"> Feet</label>
        <input type="number" id="inches" min="0" max=".11" step=".01" required><label for="inches"> Inches</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="weight">Weight</label>:
        <input type="number" id="weight" min="0" max="1400" step=".01"required><label for="weight"> Pounds</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

    <br>
    <br>
    <h1 id="finalResult"></h1>
    <img id="img" src="" height="auto" width="500px">


    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//[weight (lb) / height (in) / height (in)] x 703

document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (document.querySelector("#feet").reportValidity() &&
        document.querySelector("#inches").reportValidity() &&
        document.querySelector("#weight").reportValidity()) {
        let heightFeet = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#feet").value);
        let heightInches = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#inches").value);
        let height = (heightFeet * 12) + (heightInches * 10);
        let weight = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#weight").value);
        let bmi = (weight / height / height) * 703;

        if (bmi < 18.5) {
            document.querySelector("#finalResult").innerHTML = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, indicating your weight is in the UNDER WEIGHT RANGE for adults of your height.`
            document.querySelector("#img").src = "/img/underWeight.jpg";
        }
        else if(bmi < 24.9 && bmi >= 18.5){
            document.querySelector("#finalResult").innerHTML = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, indicating your weight is in the HEALTHY WEIGHT RANGE for adults of your height.`
            document.querySelector("#img").src = "/img/healthyWeight.jpg";};
        else if(bmi < 29.9 && bmi >= 24.9){
            document.querySelector("#finalResult").innerHTML = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, indicating your weight is in the OVER WEIGHT RANGE for adults of your height.`
            document.querySelector("#img").src = "/img/overWeight.jpg";};
        else if(bmi<35 && bmi >=29.9>){
            document.querySelector("#finalResult").innerHTML = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, indicating your weight is in the OBESE WEIGHT RANGE for adults of your height.`
            document.querySelector("#img").src = "/img/obeseWeight.jpg";};
        else if(bmi>= 35){
            document.querySelector("#finalResult").innerHTML = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, indicating your weight is in the EXTREME OBESE WEIGHT RANGE for adults of your height.`
            document.querySelector("#img").src = "/img/extremeObeseWeight.jpg";};
        else{
            alert("ERROR!")
        };

    }
});
```

the h1 and the img should be appearing after clicking the button with the correct low bmi entered for the if statement, but nothing is happening. im not getting the validation checks either.
the way the code is worded is as it has to be for the class. i cannot add things or rewrite the code using a different methodologies that have not been taught in this class.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Also, you need an extra ( here: let bmi = (  (  weight/height/height)*703).toFixed(1);

Comment: @KostasMinaidis Error handling response: TypeError: self.processResponse is not a function at html:1. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code had multiple errors that were shown in the console. Always check the browser's console first for any suspicious messages.

After fixing all the errors, your function works.

```
<script>
    document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (document.querySelector("#feet").reportValidity() &&
            document.querySelector("#inches").reportValidity() &&
            document.querySelector("#weight").reportValidity()) {
            let heightFeet = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#feet").value);
            let heightInches = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#inches").value);
            let height = (heightFeet * 12) + (heightInches * 10);
            let weight = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#weight").value);
            let bmi = (weight / height / height) * 703;

            if (bmi < 18.5) {
                document.querySelector("#finalResult").innerHTML = `Your BMI is ${bmi}, indicating your weight is in the UNDER WEIGHT RANGE for adults of your height.`
                document.querySelector("#img").src = "/img/underWeight.jpg";
            }

        }
    });
</script>
```